# Taking a picture and displaying it effect in flutter

Tags: flutter

goal: display an image picked inside a circle.

issue: the image picked is clipped on the sides.

Here is the one that I am using to display the image:

```
CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.file(_photo!,
              width: 100, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
        ),
      )
```

the code above is used to display the image after I take a picture from the phone

this is what it looks like[image: clipedImage]

The image should look like this :: [image: not clipped image]

this is the code snip for when the image is being displayed correctly:

```
Widget _buildProfileImage() => CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: _cloudUser.userImage,
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
          radius: 50,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_cloudUser.userImage),
        ),
      );
```

the code above is used to display the image that was stored on firebase

I am pretty sure that the issue is with the widget 'ClipRRect' but I dont know what other widget I can use. or maybe thats not the issue at all idk.

Comment: Change ``fit: BoxFit.fitHeight`` to ``fit: BoxFit.cover``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `FittedBox` widget

Change this:

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50.0,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
      child: Image.file(_photo!,
          width: 100, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
    ),
  )
```

to this code below:

```
 ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
   child: FittedBox(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   child: Image.file(_photo!)),
       ),
    ),
```